# Create collection to print a map of month days and some values only on days with values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a custom colletion, of a specific User who hasMany Sessions.

the idea is to generate a table with days of month and User rating of those Lessons like this image:

| Day | Rating |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 |  |
| ... |  |
| 30 |  |

I started with the following code:

```php
$user = User::where('id', $request->id)->with('lessons')->first();
$a = 1;
$collection = new Collection();
while ($a <= date('d')) {
   $date = new Carbon(date('Y').date('m').$a);
   $collection->push((object)[
      'date' => $a,
      'rating'=> $user->lesson->where('date', $date->toDateString())->first() ?
         $user->lesson->where('date', $date->toDateString())->first()->get('rating') : 
         null

   ]);
   $a++;
}
```

What I think is wrong here:

`'rating'=> $user->lesson->where('date', $date->toDateString())->first() ? $user->lesson->where('date', $date->toDateString())->first()->get('rating') : null`

This returns a collection of Ratings of this user only with one value, 5 on day 4 and rest null:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

What is teh way to achieve this correctly?
`'rating'=> $user->lesson->where('date', $date->toDateString())->first() ? $user->lesson->where('date', $date->toDateString())->first()->get('rating') : null`

Thanks!

***UPDATE***

Since I can't find a better solution, I went with this and I think it works pretty well!

````
        $user = Patient::where('id', $request->id)->with('clinic_session')->with('financial_movement')->first();
    
        $a = 1;
        $end = $this->getDaysInMonth($current_month);
        $data = new Collection();
        while ($a <=  $end) {
                    $date = new Carbon(date('Y').date('m').$a);
                    $financial = $user->financial_movement->where('date', $date->toDateString())->first() ? $user->financial_movement->where('date', $date->toDateString())->first() : null;
                    $data->push((object)['day' => $a,
                                            'session'=> $user->clinic_session->where('date', $date->toDateString())->first() ? $user->clinic_session->where('date', $date->toDateString())->first()->date_start : null,
                                            'payment'=> $financial ? $financial->value : null,
                                            'method'=> $financial ? $financial->method : null,
                                            'notes'=> $financial ? $financial->notes : null,

                    ]);
                    $a++;
                }
  
        
        return view('backend.financials.show')->with('user', $user)->with('data', $data);

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2JyS.png
````

Comment: Can you show us your table structure, example data, and expected output

Comment: example output is table where I have a 2 dimensions table with day of maonth and rating value of class that user went to, if he went to some, its the first table of my post @YahyaUddin